# If a prototype is changed, will this affect current instances?

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

Say I have this:

```
var _JS = function() {
  this.Constants = {
    True: 1,
    False: 0,
    Nil: null,
    Unknown: void(0),
  };
};

var JS = new _JS();
```

If I change it afterwards (add methods, using `_JS.prototype.etc`), can I call those methods on `JS`?

Comment: You aren't using a prototype.

Comment: No, I am changing the prototype of a function. :) This is not about the library indeed.

Comment: Um, couldn't you have figure it out yourself testing it? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, a prototype change affects all instances of the item whose prototype you modified.

See example of a simple prototype modification: http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/56Wdw/1/

Comment: +1 This is awesome. (Otherwise I couldn't use `JS.Constants` :)). Will accept after waiting period of 10 minutes.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Modifying a prototype modifies all instances.

A simple test:

```
var f = function(){}
var g = new f()
f.prototype.trace = function(){alert(1)}
g.trace(); // alerts 1
```

Answer (score 3):

> If a prototype is changed, will this affect current instances?

Yes. If you change the prototype that existing object instances share, it will change for all of them.

Answer (score 3):

The following code would print something:

```
var ajs = new _JS();
_JS.prototype.do = function () {console.log('something');}
ajs.do();
```